# Updating a LocalDB file in Visual Studio Express 2012 (C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, localdb

I have been building an application where I decided that a database was needed, after doing a little research I stumbled across LocalDB and how it could be of use to me.

To test this new system I have created a test application with the sole purpose of connecting to a LocalDB database and then checking the various commands that can be used to manipulate data through Code.

I followed a guide to create the database, add it into Visual Studio, and then create a data connection.

After doing this, and adding a view of the database to the form, I then created a button with the following code.

```
    private void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataRow newLocationRow = dBTestSet.exitLogsLocation.NewRow();

        newLocationRow["locationName"] = "Test";
        newLocationRow["fileLocation"] = "Test";
        newLocationRow["logCount"] = 4;

        dBTestSet.exitLogsLocation.Rows.Add(newLocationRow);

        exitLogsLocationTableAdapter.Update(newLocationRow);

    }
```

With the purpose literally being to add a new row to the table and then save to the database.

This is the point where I get stuck. The program adds the new row to the data grid view thats on the form, but doesnt actually commit to the database.

I think I'm probably missing something really basic here, but after looking online for any explanation, I am at a loss.

I tried to add some pictures to aid with this query but I do not have enough reputation to do so, I would upload them to an image sharing site, but I'm not sure if that's allowed.

Apologies if this is a silly question, and by all means please ask me for any information I may have missed out.

Thanks in advance,

Will

Comment: wrap your update in a try catch and tell us the error you get

Comment: I wrapped it in a try catch block, but the program isn't actually throwing any errors. It updates the datagrid view on the form with the new row, and continues running normally.

Comment: visual studio actually maintains two db file. one ins solution folder and other in bin folder. your data is saved in db file of bin folder while you're trying to open file from solutions folder. try to open db file from bin directory.

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you so much, I feel like an idiot but I'm so glad that was it! Please post this as an actual answer so I can mark this as solved :]

Comment: posted as an actual answer @WaterClock

Answer (score 2, accepted):

visual studio actually maintains two db file. one is in solution folder and other in bin folder. your data is saved in db file of bin folder while you're trying to open file from solutions folder. try to open db file from bin directory.